# How to approximate $f(x-1)-f(x)$ with Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Given a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, which is infinitely many times differentiable, how can one express the difference
$$
f(x-1)-f(x), \quad x\in\mathbb{N}
$$
with the help of Taylor series? I have come across the formula
$$
f(i-1)-f(i)=-\frac{f^{\prime}(i)}{1 !}+\frac{f^{\prime \prime}(i)}{2 !}-\frac{f^{\prime \prime \prime}(i)}{3 !}+\cdots,\quad i\in \mathbb{N}
$$
but don't exactly know how it can be obtained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, go to the definitions and see what happens!

By definition, the Taylor series for $f(x)$ centered at $i$ is

$$f(x) = f(i) + \frac{f'(i)}{1!}(x - i) + \frac{f''(i)}{2!}(x - i)^2 + \cdots$$

Taking $x = i - 1$, we have

$$f(i - 1) = f(i) + \frac{f'(i)}{1!}(i - 1 - i) + \frac{f''(i)}{2!}(i - 1 - i)^2 + \dots$$

Note that $i - 1 - i = -1$, and that $-1$ to any odd power is $-1$, while $-1$ to any even power is $1$. Thus

$$f(i - 1) = f(i) - \frac{f'(i)}{1!} + \frac{f''(i)}{2!} - \frac{f'''(i)}{3!} + \cdots$$

Finally, subtract $f(i)$ from both sides to obtain

$$f(i - 1) - f(i) = -\frac{f'(i)}{1!} + \frac{f''(i)}{2!} - \frac{f'''(i)}{3!} + \cdots$$

Interestingly, note that this is not restricted to $i \in \mathbb{N}$! It does have a different restriction, though: any Taylor series has a *radius of convergence*, outside of which the Taylor series does not converge to the value of the function. Unless the radius of convergence of the Taylor series centered at $i$ is greater than $1$, this relationship may not work.

Answer (score 3):

This expansion comes from assuming that the Taylor series of $f$ at $x$ converges to $f(x+1)$ at $x+1.$ This is much stronger than $f$ being infinitely differentiable!

Anyways, write the Taylor series at $x$ as
$$f(x) + f'(x)h + \frac{f''(x)}{2}h^2 + \frac{f'''(x)}{3!}h^3 + \cdots.$$
Plug in $h=1,$ and assuming the convergence of the Taylor series to $f$ at $h=1,$ we get
$$f(x+1) = f(x) + f'(x) + \frac{f''(x)}{2} + \cdots.$$
The $x-1$ identity can be derived by plugging in $h=-1.$ Although, again, note in general not all functions have Taylor series obeying this property!